# KVO and refactoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, refactoring, key-value-observing

Lets say that I have:

```
@property NSNumber* number;
```

And my controller is observing:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ...
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"number"]) ...
}
```

My question is - **whats your approach to refactoring the name of `number` property**?

It's obvious that I need to update observed key in observers code, but how could I do it in some smart/automatic way, and dont miss any observer watching to handle the change of my property?

Comment: What do you want to refactor? I don't even see actual code that does something.

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated I meant renaming of property and updating observed keyPath name

Answer (score 3):

One way is to declare string constants for all the properties which are being observed. Use these constants for adding observer and comparing `keypath`. You should change the value of those string constants whenever you want to rename the property.

I dont think that complete atomisation is possible.

Comment: One more way is to use reflection. If it is fixed that your number of properties and its order in the class is not going to change, you can take help of runtime functions like accessing property of a particular index.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'll respond to myself:) My solution is a mix of Apurv solution and unit testing.

Here it is:

**1** For each observed property in `MyClass` define:

`static NSString* MyClassPropertyNameNumber = @"number";`

**2** In `- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ...` implementation use **only** defined  NSStrings.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ...
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:MyClassPropertyNameNumber]) ...
}
```

**3** Write the unit test which will check if MyClass object responds to `setNumber:` and `number` selectors.

```
- (void)testMyClass
{
    SEL numberGetter = NSSelectorFromString(MyClassPropertyNameNumber);
    SEL numberSetter = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", MyClassPropertyNameNumber]);
    
    MyClass* testMyClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    if (![testMyClass respondsToSelector:numberGetter] || ![testMyClass respondsToSelector:numberSetter])
    {
        STFail(@"%@: %@ property name has changed! Please update your defined property name!", NSStringFromClass([MyClass class]), MyClassPropertyNameNumber);
    }
}
```

It will fail if you'll change property name, and dont update defined property name.

I hope it will be helpful for someone:)

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable for each observed key path, use them as contexts when registering and in the observer handler method:

```
static void * numberKVO = &numberKVO;
static void * letterKVO = &letterKVO;

...
[self addObserver:self 
       forKeyPath:@"kp.4.number" 
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
          context:numberKVO];
[self addObserver:self 
       forKeyPath:@"kp.4.letter" 
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
          context:letterKVO];   
...

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == numberKVO) {
        ...
    } else if (context == letterKVO) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can modify the properties and key paths without changing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[Mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) is a great tool when it comes to deal with Core Data model classes. It generates NSStrings for all attributes, relationships, and fetched properties in:

```
extern const struct ModelClassAttributes
extern const struct ModelClassRelationships
extern const struct ModelClassFetchedProperties
```